# How To Use "array of objects whith array" In "React-Redux-Form"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to use react-redux-form (https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form) for my first react application, but now I come to problem that I can not solve.

I want to have variable of model structured like this:

```
specialCondtions: [
   { terms: [ {obj1a},{obj2a},... ] }
   { terms: [ {obj1b},{obj2b},... ] }
   { terms: [ {obj1c},{obj2c},... ] }
   { terms: [ {obj1d},{obj2d},... ] }
]
```

So something like array of arrays. 
The problem is that at the begging I have only empty array in model

```
specialCondtions: []
```

Now first obj1a comes form user input.
I can not use this:

```
let obj={terms:[]}
obj.terms.push(obj1a)
dispatch(actions.push("model.specialCondtions",obj))
```

because I get following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

This is not async , so I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: can you show the code for actions.push?

Comment: Hey , sorry I probably did not write it correctly but I am using this [link](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form) and actions are imported from there.